# How to make a generic Type cast function to cast context to Any activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to create a generic function that allows to cast context to activity type passed in parameter.

example of the idea:

```
private fun <T> castContext(activityType: T): T{
  //example activityType = MainActivity
  return context as T
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work you need to supply the type information, normally only available at compile-time (due to type erasure). In Java you would supply instance of `Class` or a something called `type token`.

1 If the type information is available at compile-time, you can use

```
private inline fun <reified T: Any> castContext(activity: Any?): T {
  return activity as T
}
```

Inline function is a compile-time only construct and thus can 'embed' the type information into the bytecode in your stead (as in passing it explicitly as function parameter) - this is done by reifying the generic type parameter.

You could further narrow down the generic parameter bounds from `Any` to whatever you wish to specialize this function for your needs.

2 If you want to cast dynamically, to an instance of some class, unknown at compile-time, you need to do a normal cast:

```
val type: KClass<*> = ...
type.cast(instance)
type.safeCast(instance)
```

Because Kotlin's `as` and `as?` keywords are not methods (which irritates me to no end, due to often requiring extra `()` for cast, I'm using this pair of functions:

```
/** @return this as instance of the specified type (equivalent to this as T) */
inline fun <reified T: Any> Any?.asIs(): T = this as T

/** @return this as instance of the specified type (equivalent to this as? T) */
inline fun <reified T: Any> Any?.asIf(): T? = this as? T
```

The use of `Any?` as method receiver is somewhat controversial, due to handling null implicitly, instead of explicitly on call site, using `?.`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for passing by too!